# Broadcast not received from Chrome Custom Tab menu item click

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, chrome-custom-tabs

I am doing the following within a Fragment (condensed for convenience):

```
intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
String label = "Test";
PendingIntent pendingIntent = createPendingIntent(ActionBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_TEST);
intentBuilder.addMenuItem(label, pendingIntent);

CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(
                    getActivity(), intentBuilder.build(), mUri, null);


private PendingIntent createPendingIntent(int actionSourceId) {
    Intent actionIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            ActionBroadcastReceiver.class);
    actionIntent.putExtra(ActionBroadcastReceiver.KEY_TEST, actionSourceId);

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(), actionSourceId, actionIntent, 0);
}
```

Then I have an `ActionBroadCastReceiver` class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(ActionBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "Broadcast Received");

Toast.makeText(context, "Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

My log call does not appear and neither does the toast message when the menu item is clicked, which leads me to believe the broadcast is never sent nor received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an action to your broadcast.

Register it in manifest file like this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.app.MyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.app.SOME_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And setup intent like this:

```
Intent actionIntent = new Intent("com.example.app.SOME_ACTION");
```

Comment: The problem was I never registered it in my manifest. `<receiver android:name="com.example.app.MyReceiver">` inside the application tag was all I needed. Thank you!