# intercepting SMS messages from android browsers

Tags: javascript, android, sms

One of our customers is interested in capturing text messages and displaying them in user's mobile browser.

I've read several threads about intercepting SMS messages in Android apps (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853205/broadcast-not-received-from-chrome-custom-tab-menu-item-click)), and from what I understand you are only able to do so if you have an app that extends `BroadcastReceiver` in its code.

So the question is: do Chrome Mobile and Android Browser implement this technique in some way, and do they have some kind of javascript API for accessing this functionality?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it would be a huge security issue if this was possible.

Comment: @Compufreak well - you can ask user for permissions, same as when you ask for pemissions to access camera.

Comment: Fair enough - I still don't like the idea of stacking browsers with features like this, as it makes a system quite more vulnerable in case of an exploit in the browser.. For an often used (and probably standardized) feature like camera or microphone the risk might be worth the reward, but for an platform-specific edge-case like reading SMS it isn't in my opinion, and AFAIK also isn't implemented anywhere.